# Set different fonts for different charsets

Tags: init-file, fonts

I'm new to Emacs, and would like to know how to append my init.el file to use specific fonts for different languages. Specifically, for English (and other Latin-based languages, I guess) I would like Emacs to use DeJaVu Mono, but for Thai I would like it to use TH Sarabun

I have read https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fontsets.html and will admit that I understand nothing on that page.

I'm actually trying to set up emacs to be an environment to write linguistic documentation, and am not a programmer, though I am willing to learn, though perhaps I need some hand holding, as I've never attempted something like this before.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider filing a doc bug (enhancement request), mentioning specifics as much as possible (just which parts are unclear to you etc.). To do that: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. This could help a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following function to set Latin characters and Japanese characters separately.

Full configuration: https://github.com/kaz-yos/emacs/blob/5fe90b4256de8d85c1c85fa39139a7ba944ea073/init.d/200_language-and-font-related.el#L33-L65

```el
(defun update-current-frame-fontset-mac ()
  "Update current frame fontset with Japanese font setting (macOS)"
  (let* (;; Ascii font name (pick from (font-family-list))
         (my-ascii-font "Menlo")
         ;; Japanese font name (pick from (font-family-list))
         (my-jp-font    "Hiragino Maru Gothic ProN")
         ;; Create :family-only font specifications (use later)
         ;; #<font-spec nil nil Menlo nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil>
         (my-ascii-fontspec (font-spec :family my-ascii-font))
         ;; #<font-spec nil nil Hiragino\ Maru\ Gothic\ ProN nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil>
         (my-jp-fontspec    (font-spec :family my-jp-font)))
    ;;
    ;; Return the value of FACE’s ATTRIBUTE on (current) FRAME.
    ;; (face-attribute 'default :fontset) returns the current frame's fontset,
    ;; which can be updated for some letters via set-fontset-font

    ;; For these Japanese character sets, use my-jp-fontspec
    (set-fontset-font (face-attribute 'default :fontset)
                      'japanese-jisx0213.2004-1 my-jp-fontspec    nil 'append)
    (set-fontset-font (face-attribute 'default :fontset)
                      'japanese-jisx0213-2      my-jp-fontspec    nil 'append)
    ;; For Half-sized katakana characters, use my-jp-fontspec
    (set-fontset-font (face-attribute 'default :fontset)
                      'katakana-jisx0201        my-jp-fontspec    nil 'append)
    ;;
    ;; For the characters in the range #x0080 - #x024F, use my-ascii-fontspec
    ;; Latin with pronounciation annotations
    (set-fontset-font (face-attribute 'default :fontset)
                      '(#x0080 . #x024F)        my-ascii-fontspec nil 'append)
    ;; For the characters in the range #x0370 - #x03FF, use my-ascii-fontspec
    ;; Greek characters
    (set-fontset-font (face-attribute 'default :fontset)
                      '(#x0370 . #x03FF)        my-ascii-fontspec nil 'append)))
```